# Listbox multiple selection matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-gui

I created a `listbox` and enabled multiple selections. My `listbox` contain numbers from 1 to 10. When I select 3, 1, and 8, the function always put my selections in alphabetical order (1,3,8). Is there any way I could make it not put my selection in alphabetical order? So if I select 3, 1, and 8 the output of my selection is 3, 1, 8.

Thank you.

Comment: please post a minimal example and a screenshot of your problem. Nobody will rebuild your gui just to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3):

For the purpose of this answer I'm assuming you're using [matlab-hg2](/questions/tagged/matlab-hg2).

---

From the docs for [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html#zmw57dd0e785704):

> - `'listbox'` ... The `Value` property stores the row indexes of currently selected list box items, and is a vector value when you select multiple items. After any mouse button up event that changes the `Value` property, MATLAB evaluates the list box's callback routine. To delay action when multiple items can be selected, you can associate a "Done" push button with the list box. Use the callback for that button to evaluate the list box `Value` property.

From the above we learn that the information on the selected lines is returned in `Value`. From there, it's a matter of keeping track of what's selected. This can be quite easily done using a `persistent` variable inside the listbox' `Callback` as shown in the following example:

```
function LISTBOX_EXAMPLE
hFig = figure('Units','Pixels','Position', [200 200 100 200],'Menubar','none');
uicontrol(hFig, ...
  'Style', 'listbox',...
  'Units','Pixels',...
  'Position', [20 20 80 150],...
  'Max',3,...
  'Min',0,...
  'String',num2cell(1:10),...
  'Callback',@selectionCallback);

  function selectionCallback(hObject,~)
    persistent previouslyChosenItems
    %// Elements were added:    
    if numel(previouslyChosenItems) < numel(hObject.Value)
      previouslyChosenItems = union(previouslyChosenItems,hObject.Value,'stable');
    %// Elements were removed:
    elseif numel(previouslyChosenItems) > numel(hObject.Value)
      previouslyChosenItems = intersect(previouslyChosenItems,hObject.Value,'stable');
    %// A different element was selected (single element):
    elseif numel(previouslyChosenItems) == numel(hObject.Value) && numel(hObject.Value)==1
      previouslyChosenItems = hObject.Value;
    end
    disp(['Currently selected items (in order): ' num2str(previouslyChosenItems(:)')]);
  end

end
```

Example output:

```
Currently selected items (in order): 7
Currently selected items (in order): 3
Currently selected items (in order): 3  9
Currently selected items (in order): 3  9  1
```

Then it's up to you to assign the value of `previouslyChosenItems` somplace useful.